# Make the submit question title field default to sentence casing in the android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, android-app

Very minor I know but when focusing on the title field of the submit a question screen the keyboard is lower case.

I think it should default to sentence casing, which is what the body field does.

I'm using swiftkey on an S2 if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done in the next release, thanks!

Comment: Test comment. Please ignore.

Comment: I've just gone to submit a question and on my Samsung s2 with SwiftKey and it's trying to capitalise every word. I was expecting it to be sentence case. I originally asked for title case in error, but someone pointed out I meant sentence casing. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Done in next release 2: This time actually done.