# Suddenly all answers disappear after commenting

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I opened [a question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2912/why-does-kakashi-hatake-always-wear-a-mask), commented on one of the two answers, then pulled to refresh and then suddenly this -

[image]

I moved back to list of questions and entered the question again, but it's still empty. What did I break?

**Update**: I just commented on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193095/162376), and the same thing happened. The answer window went empty and this time without even pulling for refresh.

Comment: I don't know what you did, but it seems you've broken Imgur here. :)

Comment: Sorry about that. :P

Comment: Where can I get debug log? Are they sent automatically to the wizard who is building this?

Comment: Logs are sent automatically if the app crashes/force closes. Getting a log outside of that situation is kind of a pain because of the way Android 4.1+ restricts log access on the device. Unless you have adb installed on your computer, wait until the devs ask you for it before spending the time venturing down that path

Comment: @StevenV well I have my phone rooted and reading logcat is pretty easy so I did it anyway. :P But there doesn't seem to be any exception except a generic error `SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length`

Comment: Ah, rooted then you're golden. My apologies. I had to send a log over to the guys in a previous post and I was pretty surprised at how little output logging it does compared to others.

Comment: Actually there are several level of logs: verbose, debug, info, error etc. By default it uses verbose I think. I checked debug and info too.

Answer (score 2):

This would have been the same issue as [Question loading failed in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193156/question-loading-failed-in-android-app), and should be fixed now.

Comment: Was it fixed in last 24 hours?

Comment: Yes, see my answer to the other question.