# Question loading failed in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, android-app

Up-vote or down-vote any question and try to load the same question again, it fails!

And even after clicking Retry, it's not getting loaded any how.

**App version:** 0.1.9

[image]

Comment: I noticed this after upvoting a comment.  Was going to post a screenshot of it tomorrow.

Comment: Please specify the app version in reports like this (you can find it via Menu -> Help).

Comment: @balpha included in question and its 0.1.9. Is it reproducible at your end?

Comment: Thanks. After a bit of digging, I actually think this is an API problem, not an app problem. But yes, I'm seeing similar issues.

Comment: @balpha Is it resolved (because still its not getting loaded) or will resolve it later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a bug in our API. After actions like voting, we have to ensure that the next API response doesn't come from the cache, so we have the correct score in the response. This cache breaking accidentally caused the response "this question doen't exist" instead of "this question doesn't exist *in cache*."

Fixed now.

Comment: Great work and it was indeed quick solution ;) Thanks