# Auto-capitalisation doesn't work when flagging posts from the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, android-app

When I try to flag a post for moderator attention from the Android app, the first letter of each sentence - first word in the text, or anything following a full stop - is not automatically capitalised. Below is a screenshot of a sample flag:

[image: broken auto-capitalisation]

If you look closely you'll notice that after the last full stop the switch key isn't highlighted as it should be, and all the letters are lower caps by default.

Auto capitalisation is a feature I activated in the settings for the Android keyboard. The strange thing is that it works fine when entering text in any other text box, be it for posting a question, an answer, or a comment. I'm using Android 4.4.4 on a Nexus 5.

Comment: Well, in the beginning nothing had the "auto capitalisation" activated, we need to ask for this, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192990/make-the-submit-question-title-field-default-to-sentence-casing-in-the-android-a.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'll change bug to feature request then. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

Fun fact.  In Android, this can be done two ways.  Not sure which way is better but I'm going with the second because it most closely resembles what's done in other XML layouts.

```
commentText.setKeyListener(new TextKeyListener(TextKeyListener.Capitalize.SENTENCES, true));

commentText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT);
```